# Stack Overflow closed my account due to upvoting my friends

Tags: support, voting, deleted-accounts

Why did Stack Overflow delete my account without any warning? They said that: "You are fake" I had just upvoted one of my friend's post. They closed my account without any warning.

The worst things is that they did not answer me and keep ignoring me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Upvoting your friends is not allowed here. While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the *post*, **not the person who wrote it.**

Stack Exchange works by ensuring that the best information rises to the top. Voting specifically for content that benefits your friends, family or colleagues unfairly skews that system.

The moderator that deleted your account assumed you were a [sockpuppet account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) for your friend, and acted accordingly. Since you upvoted **all eighteen** of your friends posts (not just one), that is not surprising.

If you can refrain from voting for your friend's posts in the future, you are welcome to use your new account.

Comment: So, if H. Aqjn is not a sockpuppet, will she be let back in?

Comment: @EmilVikström: they already re-created their account. Provided they refrain from targeted voting, that's fine, we don't hold grudges.

Comment: Well, 0 votes so far, guess that only the friends' posts were considered good enough to upvote.

Comment: However ur punishment is too severe for my guilt, you should devote the votes of my friend and give a warning message to me, and if I repeat my fault u could cut my head.

Comment: You got the same punishment all sockpuppets get.

Comment: @H.Aqjn: your behaviour was indistinguishable from a sock puppet. Note that there were other connection between you and your friend as well, such as your friend answering your question. All evidence taken together, the moderator was convinced you were not a real account, and the standard response is to delete sock puppet accounts. It is regrettable that your account turned out to be real here.

Comment: @H.Aqjn: I think the community is reacting to what they perceive as immoral behaviour on your side. Voting is taken very seriously here, and voting for your friend just because he is your friend is regarded as cheating. On top of that they may feel you lied in your post, by saying you voted on *one* post by your friend. You voted on **all** posts by your friend, not just one.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters you don't know my friend and I know him in 15 years ago.
I know that he is so smart and has a very intelligent mind. So as I know him I upvoted all of his answer.

Comment: @HoseinAqajani I think the point is you're only meant to upvote an answer if it helped you. It's obvious this is not the case and you were simply upvoting because it's your friend. You say your friend is smart, well if everyone upvoted based on how smart a person is and not based on whether or not the answer helped, then we may as well get rid of the voting system.

Answer (score 10):

> Why did Stack Overflow delete my account without any warning? ... I had just upvoted one of my friend's post.

First, a moderator doesn't delete an account without any good reason to do so. Your own remark makes clear your account was deleted for being a serial voter or a sock puppet, someone who votes for a user instead of his/her posts. Since we find quality important, this is not allowed. It is cheating! I seriously doubt if you really just voted once, or if you voted a lot more. In fact, you know what is wrong since you say you just voted once. Maybe you have multiple accounts that voted multiple times on the same user.

> The worst things is that they did not answer me and keep ignoring me.

Give it some time. Moderators are very busy moderating the site and handling cases like this. Usually it will take a few days, a week maybe, before they respond. (Since you are on the naughty bench, don't expect they run to you immediately if you 'scream' to them)

Comment: Honestly I vote to one of my friend for multiple times but I did not know this rule, and they never warn me through a simple warning message.
They only send a message to my friend that Husein.aghajani@gmail.com is a fake email, and then remove me.
I have some very good question and I have earned 86 reputations.
Why do this to me?

Comment: He just explained why! Wow.

Comment: I think you should think more what consequences some actions would have. Does it seem honest to you to up-vote your friend multiple times? What if you up-voted me 100 times? Is that fair to other users contributing? I think not. It is all described that this isn't allowed, it just isn't presented that prominently to anyone (you can find it in the help, maybe the privilege page should be extended a little on this).