# Avoid being banned when introducing others to SE

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, ethics, sock-puppets, ban

In order to get my girlfriend to join Stack Exchange, I sometimes write questions using her account and upvote these question with my own account.

I'm not doing this because she is my girlfriend and I want to give her reputation, but because she isn't an English native speaker (although I'm not one either), and is not familiar with MarkDown or MathJax or the SE community. I write these questions for her to show her how to write good questions, and upvote them because I think they are good.

It may seem suspicious when one account keeps upvoting posts of another account. So my question is: would such behavior trigger any anti-cheating script, or be treated as cheating by the community?

---

**Follow Up:**

I understand now that I shouldn't upvote a question I write which is posted by another account. However, here come another question:

If I just sit near her when she's writing questions and critique them, is it allowed to upvote these question, for I think they are good question after my modification?

Although this behavior is still indistinguishable from sock puppetry for anti-cheating scripts, I personally think it's moral.

Comment: Better to let her write her own questions. Then review them before she posts them.

Comment: You write questions that you think are good, to show her how to write them. And then you think "boy, that's a good question, that deserves an upvote" ... and you wonder if that's okay ... Besides whether or not scripts would detect it (they will), you don't see other problems with that approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: This is cheating, no matter how you look at it, and not different even one bit from upvoting your own questions.

Comment: Upvoting because of the author, and not the question, is called abusing the voting system

Comment: Also, I really hope you didn't use your girlfriend's account to upvote this very question.

Comment: "Although this behavior is still indistinguishable from sock puppetry for anti-cheating scripts, I personally think it's moral." Morality is determined by the individual, Ethics is determined by a community of people.  Neither have anything to do with voting fraud, a policy enforced by a community, yes voting for your friends question (just because they are your friend) is voting fraud.  Your "girlfriend" should stick to subjects she understands enough to ask her own questions about

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> In order to get my girlfriend join Stack Exchange, sometimes I write questions using her account and upvote these question with my own account.

I feel this question is going the wrong way...

> I write these questions for her to show her how to write good questions, and upvote them because I think they are good.

You really shouldn't. You should refrain from voting on your 'own' posts, posted under another account basically. I understand the thing you are doing here, but you should let the community vote on such posts.

And yes, it will trigger voting fraud scripts, as it should. We really appreciate you want to help users to become a member here, but such voting patterns are hard to distinguish from classic serial voting, and it even might end you up with the accounts merged.

Answer (score 21):

> In order to get my girlfriend to join Stack Exchange, I sometimes write questions using her account

This isn't going to help her "join" Stack Exchange any more than you reading books for her will help her join the library.

Even ignoring the artificial reputation you're creating by upvoting your own questions after making them, the fact that you are writing the questions means she's already receiving reputation you believe she wouldn't receive posing her own questions.

Further, she doesn't get the experience to learn how to write good questions if you're doing the work for her.

Ultimately it does her no good.  When she does write her own questions she may end up doing badly and leaving even after all your work.

I strongly suggest that instead you sit near her when she's writing questions and critique them, teaching her how best to ask questions that get answered.  It will be much more a benefit to her than simply writing them for her.

Answer (score 10):

This is absolutely forbidden. Having multiple accounts is not a problem at all, so writing questions with the new account is fine, but **don't cast any votes** you couldn't with only a single account. (This also means not upvoting a random Jon Skeet answer with both accounts.)

Answer (score 8):

Adding to other great answers,

> I write these questions for her to show her how to write good
>   questions,

There are many other questions with a lot of upvotes and high-quality answers. You can show them to her as example questions.

> and upvote them because I think they are good.

If you think they are good, other users might also think they are good. Let others vote for them on behalf of you. Don't vote for her. They will upvote or downvote for you and let her see the results.

Answer (score 6):

With the edit, your question becomes: "Can I vote on questions and answers posted by my friends?"

This was already asked in [Stack Overflow closed my account due to upvoting my friends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266666/stack-overflow-closed-my-account-due-to-upvoting-my-friends), and as [the top answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266669/152859) (by Stack Overflow moderator) there says:

> Upvoting your friends is not allowed here. While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the post, not the person who wrote it.

So the answer, as all others said, is still  a plain "no". You will still be banned if you vote on your friends' posts, even if you think they are good.

That said, if you are regular member, very active on the site, and got lots of friends over the time, this does not mean you can't vote on any post by someone you know. The above applies to users who are not very active, and vote *only*, or *mainly* on posts written by people they actually know.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you describe would most likely be indistinguishable from sock puppetry and treated as such.

See [How can you detect if users have created sock puppet accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35989/215590)

I strongly recommend that you do not continue to do this.